# Issue with HdInsight cluster creation with additional storage accounts

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I am having an issue while creating HdInsight cluster. This functionality is fundamental to a POC I am doing.

I am trying to add an additional storage account to the cluster.

Here is my code:

```
private static void CreateCluster(HDInsightCertificateCredential creds)
    {
        var client = HDInsightClient.Connect(creds);


        var clusterInfo = new ClusterCreateParameters()
        {
            Name = Clustername,
            Location = Location,
            DefaultStorageAccountName = Storageaccountname,
            DefaultStorageAccountKey = Storageaccountkey,
            DefaultStorageContainer = Containername,
            UserName = Username,
            Password = Password,
            ClusterSizeInNodes = Clustersize
        };

        //clusterInfo.AdditionalStorageAccounts.Add(new WabStorageAccountConfiguration("sacvendor.blob.core.windows.net", "<mykey>"));


        client.CreateCluster(clusterInfo);

        Console.WriteLine("done creating cluster");
    }
```

Everything works fine with

```
//clusterInfo.AdditionalStorageAccounts.Add(new WabStorageAccountConfiguration("sacvendor.blob.core.windows.net", "<mykey>"));
```

Line commented out

But when this line is not commented out the code fails with Task failed exception. On the Management portal I can see the cluster with Error status and error message says internal server error retry the request.

The following blog describes the exact same process.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/04/15/customizing-hdinsight-cluster-provisioning-via-powershell-and-net-sdk.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a bug in azure, this will not work until this bug is fixed. a work around is to provide a container name with the AdditionalStorageAccounts call

clusterInfo.AdditionalStorageAccounts.Add(new WabStorageAccountConfiguration(".blob.core.windows.net", "", "mycontainer"));

Answer (score 1):

This bug fix will be rolled out by Tuesday, 2nd September. Sorry about the inconvenience caused.

Thanks,
Augustine Mathew
SDE II HDInsight
MSFT

Answer (score 0):

This issue also occurs when trying to create via PowerShell. Unfortunately, the Add-AzureHDInsightStorage CmdLet does not have a Container parameter.

Is there a known workaround for PowerShell?